# Git deploy script make it show a response

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, github

I am using the script below to automatically deploy my CI site to the staging server from GIT.

My issue is that I am a noob when it comes to GIT and the code does not seem to be pushing to the server when I do a push to the repository.

Is there anyway that I can make the script below give a response code like 200 etc.  The hook setup on git hub is set to use JSON.

**Script:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Post-Receive Hooks API
 *
 * @author      appleboy
 * @copyright   2012 appleboy
 * @link        https://github.com/appleboy/PHP-Git-Deploy
 * @package     CodeIgniter Git Deploy
 */
class Deploy extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * Default __construct
     *
     * @author appleboy
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->config->load('github');
    }

    /**
     *
     * Post-Receive Hooks
     *
     * @author appleboy
     */
    public function receive()
    {
        // receive git payload
        $payload = $this->input->get_post('payload');
        // load git command path config
        $git_config = $this->config->item('github');
        $git_path = $this->config->item('git_path');

        if ($payload and is_array($git_config)) {
            $payload = json_decode($payload);

            log_message('debug', 'Post-receive hook initial');

            foreach ($git_config as $key => $val) {

                // check repository name exist in config
                $repository_name = strtolower($payload->repository->name);
                if ($repository_name != strtolower($key)) {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
                    // check if match payload ref branch
                    $head = 'refs/heads/' . $k;
                    if ($payload->ref != $head) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // git reset head and pull origin branch
                    if (isset($v['base_path']) and !empty($v['base_path'])) {
                        $base_path = realpath($v['base_path']) . '/';

                        $shell = sprintf('%s --git-dir="%s.git" --work-tree="%s" reset --hard HEAD',
                            $git_path, $base_path, $base_path);
                        log_message('debug', '$shell value ' . $shell);
                        $output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($shell));

                        $shell = sprintf('%s --git-dir="%s.git" --work-tree="%s" clean -f',
                            $git_path, $base_path, $base_path);
                        log_message('debug', '$shell value ' . $shell);
                        $output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($shell));

                        $shell = sprintf('%s --git-dir="%s.git" --work-tree="%s" pull origin %s',
                            $git_path, $base_path, $base_path, $k);
                        log_message('debug', '$shell value ' . $shell);
                        $output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($shell));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can make the script below give a response code like 200 etc.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

will emit a `200 OK` but that doesn't mean the code will get pulled to the server.

Github hooks don't push to the server, the hook simply "ping"'s your server from which you then run something to do the `pull` of the fresh code from Github.

Check your `pull` code.

IMO a bash script can sometimes be more straightforward for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for that.  All I am running from the server is git pull and its running with out asking for login details.  I am using https://github.com/appleboy/PHP-Git-Deploy/blob/master/codeigniter/config/github.php

Comment: You can't pull from github with credentials, you have to use keys https://github.com/settings/ssh https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys If you haven't set up keys yet for this server, that may very well be the problem.